# Avoiding "side effects" in recursive functions

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

I am writing a function to find the intersection between two sets.

The non-functional requirements of the assignment include avoiding [**"side effects"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

```
function intersection(a, b) {
  return helper(a, b, []);
}

function helper(a, b, c) {
  if (a.length == 0) {
    return c;
  }

  if (b.contains(a[0])) {
    return helper(a.slice(1, a.length), b, c.concat([a[0]]));
  }

  return helper(a.slice(1, a.length), b, c);
}
```

Would mutating the argument `c` in the above code be considered a side effect?

The specific assignment is written in OCaml, so, though the above example is in an imperative language, I want to stay true to the spirit of functional programming.

Please don't provide any alternate solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `helper` function mutated the object `c` (which `concat` **doesn't** do in JS), then `helper` would have that side effect. But overall your `intersection` function wouldn't have any side effect that I can see, as the c array doesn't exist outside of it.

PS: `concat` returns a new array every time. The original c array is unchanged.